# ssl or https what is most useful in this case

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl

Want to have a ssl C# server that will only send and receive small JSON strings.

The clients can be anything from mobile devices or computers.

Need some feedback what to chose since some clients maybe have ssl limitations or other limitations.

Should i create an (openssl)ssl ftp socket server?
Should i create an HTTPs server?
should i create something else????

The HTTPS looks like easiest because of it's long history and width usage.

any feedback would be grate

Comment: not possible to answer as it can depend on many factors (network connectivity, control over terminals, target security level, etc.

Comment: im aware of this. Im thinking that this is not my problem and clients have to deal with this. However my idea is to create a server that is closest to fit as many client-types as possible.

Comment: Give a chance to WCF. it has a very strong customizable stack, with externalizable configuration files, for both server and client side. Moreover, it can publish services over multiples wires. This may help you to address a maximum of situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is [HTTP over SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818): you first establish an SSL/TLS connection and then you exchange HTTP requests and responses on top of it (as if it was a plain TCP connection).

Since you want to use SSL/TLS in both cases, what you seem to be asking is whether you should design your own protocol or use an existing one.

> Should i create an (openssl)ssl ftp socket server?

There are multiple ways of securing FTP with SSL/TLS. It's certainly not the easiest way to go.

> Should i create an HTTPs server? should i create something else????

Designing your own protocol means that you'll have to provide an implementation for each device yourself. HTTPS has the advantage of being widely supported. You shouldn't even have to use much of the underlying SSL/TLS API yourself (no need to learn the OpenSSL API). The only requirements might be to learn about some SSL/TLS configuration, such as setting up certificates.

Even if you're thinking of reducing the overhead due to the HTTP headers, your protocol will still have to perform similar payload management one way or another, at least to know where the requests and responses start and end.

It's unclear what your requirements are, but unless you really notice problems with HTTPS, exchanging JSON strings with HTTPS with an existing library (e.g. WCF) makes more sense than your other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Give a chance to WCF.

It has a very strong customizable stack, with externalizable configuration files, for both server and client side.

Moreover, it can publish services over multiples wires. This may help you to address a maximum of situations like "simple" https encryption to certificate validation.

You can even define your own channel for ultra specific contexts.

A last word from a developer perspective: the idea of WCF is to decouple the service from its connectivity. In today world, it's a huge advantage.

Comment: can you recommend some reading about the " decouple the service from its connectivity" and the WCF in general

Comment: Start by reading the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx). Search for WCF ABC (**A**ddress, **B**inding, **C**ontract). This is the summary of this decoupling.